# How to flatten multiple dictionary objects inside a list in pandas column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flatten

I have a df that with a column that looks like this:

```
col1

[{'value':'2019-02-02'},{'value':'test1'},{'value':'test2'},{'value':'test3'},{'value':'test4'},{'value':'test5'},{'value':'test6'}]
```

How do I flatten this column so it looks like this:

```
col1         col2
value        2019-02-02
value        test1
value        test2
value        test3
value        test4
value        test5
value        test6
```

I am trying this:

```
df['Col1'] = [x[0]['value'] for x in df['Col1']]
```

This is only picking the first value in all the nested dictionary and makign the df like this:

```
col1
2019-02-02
2019-02-02
2019-02-02
2019-02-02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `tolist` then we need `concat` with each `pd.DataFrame(sublist)`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sublist) for sublist in df.col1.tolist()]).stack().reset_index(level=1)
Out[22]: 
  level_1           0
0   value  2019-02-02
1   value       test1
2   value       test2
3   value       test3
4   value       test4
5   value       test5
6   value       test6
0   value  2019-02-02
1   value       test1
2   value       test2
3   value       test3
4   value       test4
5   value       test5
6   value       test6
```